# convert dataframe type object to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I have the dataframe `best_scores` contanining

```
     subsample colsample_bytree learning_rate max_depth min_child_weight  \
3321       0.8              0.8           0.3         2                3   

            objective  scale_pos_weight  silent  
3321  binary:logistic          1.846154       1
```

I would like to convert it in a dictionary `params` like:

```
params
{'colsample_bytree': 0.8,
  'learning_rate': 0.3,
  'max_depth': 2,
  'min_child_weight': 3,
  'objective': 'binary:logistic',
  'scale_pos_weight': 1.8461538461538463,
  'silent': 1,
  'subsample': 0.8}
```

but if I run

```
best_scores.to_dict(orient='records')
```

I get:

```
[{'colsample_bytree': 0.8,
  'learning_rate': 0.3,
  'max_depth': 2,
  'min_child_weight': 3,
  'objective': 'binary:logistic',
  'scale_pos_weight': 1.8461538461538463,
  'silent': 1L,
  'subsample': 0.8}]
```

Can you please help?

Comment: can't you do `best_scores.to_dict(orient='records')[0]`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thanks! any clue why silent is L and not int?

Comment: probably because it was initialized with a long int. You must be using python 2. You can convert back to int. Don't worry, it works fine (just taking more memory that's all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting a list of dictionaries, because you are converting a `DataFrame` to `dict`, which can potentially have multiple rows. Each row would be one entry in the list.

Apart from the mentioned solution to simply select the first entry, the ideal way to achieve what you want is to use a `Series` instead of a `DataFrame`. That way, only one `dict` is returned:

```
In [2]: s = pd.Series([1, 2 ,3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [3]: s.to_dict()
Out[3]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

In [4]: d = pd.DataFrame(s).T

In [5]: d
Out[5]: 
   a  b  c
0  1  2  3

In [6]: d.iloc[0]
Out[6]: 
a    1
b    2
c    3
Name: 0, dtype: int64

In [7]: d.iloc[0].to_dict()
Out[7]: {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```